# Currency reading in range

Tags: javascript, currency, pattern-recognition

I am working on JavaScript program which gets as input string and should return JSON or any other form with organized currency parts.

For example: `func("2 kEURO")` should return `{value:2, scalar:"thousand", currency:"EURO"}`. I have list of currency and scalar symbols but I would like to correctly read `"from 2k to 5k USD"` as well. I am using now js parser and it is enough for simple sentences.

I would like to ask if you know any others methods to make it done? I have been looking but what I found was only parsers with regex. It would be awesome if I could also read `"5k in USD, 4k in EURO"` any ideas?

Kind regards.

Comment: *"from 2k to 5k USD"* and the value is?

Comment: I thought in that case output could be for example in JSON: `{value:"2 to 5", scalar:"thousand", currency:"USD"}`. I am still working on interpretation, that is why I am looking for help.

Comment: at first think of a specific syntax. Its far to broad to be solved

Comment: So you suggest to make all possible patterns and learn program how to do interpretation?

Comment: 279 exactly. E.g. Input: *input contains comma seperated sentences. Returns: [...sentences.map(sentence)].* Sentence: *sentence is either (value)(currency), (value) in (currency) or from (value) to (value) (currency), returns {values.map(values),currency(currency)}*

Comment: Ok thanks, I will be working with this till I won't find anything better. thanks for your time - and If u find anything more, please let me know.